# Windows 2008 R2 DFS keeps MS office work-files

Tags: dfs, microsoft-office-2010

We have started using the DFS sharing functionality in Windows 2008 R2 (previously we used regular shares on Windows 2003), and noticed that for every office document we work on, it's work-file (filename starting with ~) is kept on the DFS-shared volume, so we have to erase them manually.

Did this happen to anyone else, and is this a known issue?
Searching online doesn't produce any meaningful results.

Thanks.

Comment: What are the NTFS permissions that you have setup on the DFS share?  Can you check the rights on one of the ~ files?

Comment: I have certainly never seen that.